# Console window Toggle switch

Tags: c#, console

I'm making an Console APP with menus and sub-menus. Inside some sub-menus I have ON and OFF options. For this I'd like to update my Sub-menu name from say Feed cats [OFF] to say Feed cats [ON].

Comment: Please don't fill post with fluff - instead clearly state where you stuck on one single problem. Show [MCVE] of where you stuck and explain what you want to achieve. I've edited post to show what needs to be removed. Unfortunately it is not enough to make it clear where you are stuck and what kind of help you are looking for. You need to [edit] post to clarify that.

Comment: Please also see: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and: [how to write the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try to make the [OFF] and [ON] part of the string variable. Then when you select the on / off option change the value. You did not include your code but I imagine something like this would work.

```
  public class Program {
  static string onOff = "[OFF]";

  static void Main(){
    //menu
    while(true){
      //submenu
      while(true){
        string title = $"feed cats {onOff}";
        Console.WriteLine(title);
        string option = Console.ReadLine();
        if (option == "off"){
                onOff = "[OFF]";
            } else if (option == "on"){
              onOff = "[ON]";
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```